# Return vs Response in NestJs

Tags: javascript, nestjs

I noticed that if i want to return something from an API using NESTJs, i can use `return` statement or to use `response` like that:

```js
@Controller('dashboard')
export class DashboardController {
  @Get()
  findAll(
    @Res() response: Response,
  ): any {
    response.send({
      result: JSON.stringify(['data'])
    });
  }
}
```

OR

```js
@Controller('dashboard')
export class DashboardController {
  @Get()
  findAll(
  ): any {
    return JSON.stringify(['data']);
  }
}
```

In one case i used `response.send()` and in the second `return` statement. 
 Question: What is the difference between these 2 methods?

Comment: This is explained [in the library-specific approach portion of the controller docs](https://docs.nestjs.com/controllers#library-specific-approach)

Comment: @JayMcDoniel, it is unclear. So using `return` is better than using `response`?

Comment: using `return` it's safer, I'd say. As you're delegating the "hard work" to the framework. So, to me, it's better.

Comment: Another gain when you use `return` is: you could type the method properly (let's say `Promise<UserDTO>`)  and then the `@nestjs/swagger` plugin could create the response shape automagically

Comment: It's better to use return for 1. Writing tests. 2. Using different plugins 3. Automatic type inferring 4. If u decide to use Fastify over Express u need zero code change. I'm sure there are a lot more advantages.

Comment: p.s. You don't need to stringify when returning JSON. It automatically does it for you.

Comment: @n1md7, So, if i want to use return in a service where i am using `response` (`@Res() response: Response,`), i have to add this `@Res({ passthrough: true }) res: Response,`?

Comment: I assume u mean controller instead of service (service has nothing to do with routes) then yes.